# R- Reference original raster coordinates after a projection

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, sf

My goal is to crop a raster from a sf polygon.
I have a timeseries of images, and I am clipping the same shape file from this timeseries of large raster images.
My issue is that for every image, I'm starting with a large raster that is very time consuming to project.
Here is an example of my workflow:

```
library(raster)
library(sf)

# Create data (in actual work flow, this would be a raster created from a large tiff file)
BigRaster <- raster(ncols=100, nrows=100)
BigRaster[]<-runif(ncell(BigRaster))

#Project raster to match crs of my sf object (this can take a very long time, and I'd like to avoid it)
RasterProject<-projectRaster(BigRaster, crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84", method='ngb')

#Crop projected raster based on a shape file
MyShape <- as(extent(c(xmin= -16, xmax= -7.25, ymin= 4, ymax= 12.75)), 'SpatialPolygons')
crs(MyShape)<- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"
CroppedRaster <- crop(RasterProject, MyShape)
```

To save time, I'd like to avoid projecting the entire raster every time I start with a new image. One solution would be to project the raster as above one time, and figure out the original raster coordinates for the bounding box of my shape. For the rest of the timeseries, that would allow me to crop the BigRaster object before I projected it, greatly reducing the time it takes to project. The steps of a new workflow would look like:

```
#Raster 1
Create raster object from Tiff file
Project raster to match crs of shape (takes long time)
Crop Raster based on shape
Create bounding box that references original raster coordinates

#Raster2
Crate raster object from Tiff file
Crop raster based on bounding box in step 1
Project cropped raster object (takes short time)
Crop raster based on shape
```

Comment: It might be faster to reporoject the `sf` object to match the `raster` object and then do all the cropping. Have you tried that?